# How do you change the color of the bullet points in a JFXPasswordField?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I am using Scene Builder to make a login screen.
My PasswordField's background color is gray and I would like the stars that come up when you write something to be white. They are currently black even though I set the text and prompt color to white (Which worked on the normal TextField but not here).

Where do I set the right color?

Answer (score 1):

I used `-fx-text-color` instead of `-fx-text-fill`

Answer (score 0):

There are many 2 different colors for `JFXPasswordField extends PasswordField` and moreover (`PasswordField extends TextField`):

```
this.setUnFocusColor(Paint color)
this.setFocusColor(Paint color)
```

Perhaps can it help you